# My magento page and single product content is missing on the front end only and everything is enabled. How to I flush the session data to find it?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've got an issue where only this morning my magento site at www.smartgaragestorage.com.au was working fine.  All data could be found on single product pages and actual page data was visible on the front end.

Now, after doing some work on a Temando freight extension I get only the page title on CMS pages and no data on single product pages even though each product is listed under the correct category, you can add to cart and checkout without a hitch.

Any help would be appreciated...

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: In the source I get the following only....
<div class="col-main">

<script type="text/javascript">
    Mage.Cookies.set('external_no_cache', 1);
</script>

</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the system.log, exception.log and apache error logs, this might give you some leads.

Comment: Thanks man.  Checked exception and system logs and found the problem was with meta robots extension.  Enabled in etc/modules and disabled in config/advanced... go figure.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear the magento cache, and ran the indexer?

This helps allot sometimes, to make sure it is not data issues.

Then check if anything else is wrong.

Comment: Yes I've reindexed everything and emptied all caches.  Including under var/cache and var/session.  Also emptied browser history and cache.